# Hot water heater is leaking, how much longer will it last?

Tags: leak, hot-water

This question was asked [before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/67888/hot-water-tank-leaking-at-bottom-could-it-go-from-a-trickle-to-a-gush) but the title question was not specifically answered: "Hot water tank leaking at bottom could it go from a trickle to a gush?"

I have a old hot-water heater (tank) that is starting to leak.  I knew this was likely in that the anode is completely consumed and un-serviceble (i.e. I torque the head off this summer and can see it is completely oxidized).  I've since put an electronic leak monitor device.

I want to replace the house hot-water system to tankless as well as overhaul the entire basement plumbing, but I need to wait a few months to pull the trigger, and I don't want to replace hot-water tank only to do it again a few months later.

The question is, typically, does a leak increase quickly or slowly over time?  More specifically, will that leak turn into a gusher in a matter of hours or days or weeks or months?  Is there anyway to prognosticate the likelihood of catastrophic failure?  What should I look for?

I realize the safest solution is to simply replace the heater now ("pennywise, pound foolish" was used to describe what I want to do), but I want to know if I can monitor weekly and replace if/once leak is unsustainable.

UPDATE:  I haven't found the actual leak, but lets assume it is corroded wall.

Comment: Is it leaking from a joint or has a wall corroded through?

Comment: You're living on borrowed time, my friend.  If a burst water tank will not cause any damage (i.e. the tank is outside, in an empty basement, etc.), then you can try monitoring it.  However, water can cause a **TON** of damage, so it could end up costing a lot more than a cheap temporary replacement tank. Nobody here can tell you how long it will last.  Could be 20 minutes, could be 20 years.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Let's assume it is corroded wall.   Tank is in relatively empty basement.  Most items, except furnace are off ground or waterproof or junk.  The main problem is drainage and/or lack of hot water for a while.

Comment: You could clock the time between drips after it reheats after a shower. Then log that every few days. The problem will be exacerbated by raising the temperature so the lower you keep it the better.

Comment: @codechimp If it had been a leak from a threaded joint I would have just said do not try to tighten it as that could rip the thin, corroded metal. I would be monitoring it perhaps daily.

Comment: @ArchonOSX At how many drips per second should the OP replace the heater?

Comment: @Tester101, I think the key would be to graph the drips per second (dps) over time until you could extrapolate the data to an unacceptable number of dps to find your "failure point".  I think you'd start out at fractional dps (also known as seconds per drip), and try to find the point where you would reach 3-4 dps.  Then you're going to have a steady stream, and probably want to end the experiment soon.

Comment: Make sure you consider the absolute worst case for a failure. It's not going to fail while you're checking on it, or even while you're home to hear it. It's going to fail, catastrophically, 2 minutes after you leave for work, then go out to dinner, then go see a movie. You'll come home to a water heater with the bottom joint split completely, so water has been pouring out at whatever rate the pipe can supply for the last 14 hours. It doesn't matter if everything in the basement is junk - you still have to deal with several hundred gallons to clean up and dry out. And probably mold.

Comment: @Tester101 I would recommend he replace the water heater the day before it fails catastrophically. 

Comment: Habitat for Humanity Store.   Just sayin.

Comment: Saying "hot water heater" is incorrect because if the water were hot you would not have to heat it. It is a **water heater**. Just sayin'... as I prepare for rebuttal onslaught due to OCD specific to that term and "garbage disposal", which are actually *garbage disposers*.

Comment: DPS could be used as a visual confirmation of the math, assuming the leak source is unknown. (ctrl-r or some other key often displays DPS in some worlds). Take a look at the manufacturers MTBF on the brand and model and plot it on a standard normal distribution, or exponential distribution, use a bathtub curve the manufacturer probably already has this data and might have published it. Assume a t0 of failure as in NOW and invert your distribution - the result is days before liftoff.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it my water heater heats hot water all day long. A tankless heater is a "*water heater*", a tank heater is a "*hot water heater*" most of the time. And I prefer the term "*garburator*".